# Why browser.tabs.query is not working in Edge Extension ?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge-extension

I am using below function to Get the current tab.

```
/**
 * Get the current tab.
 *
 * @param {function(tabObject)} callback - called when the URL of the current tab
 *   is found.
 */
function getCurrentTab(callback) {
// Query filter to be passed to browser.tabs.query - see
// https://developer.browser.com/extensions/tabs#method-query
var queryInfo = {
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
};
browser.tabs.query(queryInfo, function (tabs) {
    if (browser.runtime.lastError) {
        // Something went wrong
        console.warn("Whoops.. " + browser.runtime.lastError.message);
        // TODO: Show error to the user
        return false;
    } else {


        // browser.tabs.query invokes the callback with a list of tabs that match the
        // query. When the popup is opened, there is certainly a window and at least
        // one tab, so we can safely assume that |tabs| is a non-empty array.
        // A window can only have one active tab at a time, so the array consists of
        // exactly one tab.
        var tab = tabs[0];

        // A tab is a plain object that provides information about the tab.
        // See https://developer.browser.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab
        callback(tab);
    }
});

}
```

I am getting this warning Whoops.. Incorrect function.

Can someone help me with this and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code runs correctly in Edge 40.15063. Do you have 'tabs' permission in your manifest.json?

Comment: Yes I have included both tabs as well as activeTab in permissions

Comment: How about setting a breakpoint there and check if tabs/tabs[0] are defined? Maybe you can just ignore the error, or your callback is invalid, or there's more in error object. Also fiddling with queryInfo might help to detect what's broken.

Comment: @AnatolySazanov I checked and tabs[0] is undefined